# Align button at the bottom 1/3 of the screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to align a button not right at the bottom of the screen but at a slight distance above the bottom line. How can I do that? I've tried centering the button vertically and horizontally and it works, but I need to either move the button a little below the center or a little above the bottom line.

[image]

I need to move the "PLAY" button a little lower on the screen. Additionally, I also need to scale the button down a bit, to like 80% of its current size. How can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="acevix.gladiators3.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:background="@drawable/play" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried PercentRelativeLayout? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Comment: I need to add a PercentRelativeLayout inside my RelativeLayout in which I will place my button? Sorry for the probably stupid question, I'm a complete newbie

Comment: Can you show your xml file please

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry I completely forgot. I'm editing the post right now

Comment: I only said that layout because you wanted percentage. ConstraintLayout might also work. Or hard-coded margins also works

Comment: Can you give me an example of hard-coded margins?

Answer (score 1):

Use this codes,

**android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**
**android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"**
**android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"**

Try this;

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Update Code

Use this : **android:layout_below**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But I am currently using a tablet for testing, and a marginBottom of 115dp is perfect. Will the button stay in the same place on a smaller screen?

Answer (score 1):

For different screen resolutions you can use 
[**intuit/sdp**](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

add this line to your **gradle file**

**compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'**